# Using the value of indices in numpy array broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I would like to use the index values of a numpy array in broadcasting.

I am operating with a 2D numpy array. I have a function `getNeighbours(x, y, lattice, pointX, pointY)` which returns a float. The function takes in two integer arguments `x` and `y`, a 2D numpy array `lattice` and two integer arguments `pointX` and `pointY`. `pointX` and `pointY` are the indices of an element in the lattice.

I would now like to do a broadcasting operation as follows:

`sumLattice = getNeighbours(1, 2, mylattice, <xindex>, <yindex>)`

`sumLattice` should be a numpy array with the same shape as `mylattice`. Each element of `sumLattice` should contain the output of `getNeighbours` for the corresponding element in `mylattice`.

What should I put in place of `<xindex>` and `<yindex>`?

Comment: Without knowing what `getNeighbours` actually does, you could try using [`frompyfunc`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html#numpy.frompyfunc). This allows you to implement broadcasting on arbitrary functions. However, I doubt if it'll be fast. If possible, you should examine `getNeighbours` and see if it only uses Numpy operations. If so, it should be fairly easy to broadcast. Feel free to update your question if this is the case and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: `broadcasting` specifies how arrays with various shapes work together, mainly when using operators like plus and times.  It's also relevant when indexing with several dimensions.  It's not an 'iterator' mechanism by itself.  Except that `np.frompyfunc` and `np.vectorize` allow you to define functions that apply broadcasting rules to arguments of functions that normally only accept scalar inputs. BUT read their docs carefully.

Comment: It might be helpful to post the definition of `getNeighbors()` I'm not sure what the code here is intended to do.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! After learning more about broadcasting and what I'm trying to do, I've decided to not use broadcasting anymore. So I'm going to close this post.